# Type text next to an image html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, contenteditable

I would like to type text in a `contenteditable` `div` that is placed right to an image.

### HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="image">
    <img src="/path/*.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="text" contenteditable>
    <p></p>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

### CSS

```
.container {
    width: 1000px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.image, .text {
    position: relative;
}
.image {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
}
.text {
    min-height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.clear{
    clear: both;
}
```

My goal is to have the caret positioned to  the right of the image when I focus into the `contenteditable` and not to the beginning of the `p` `tag` as you can see in this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0mdcLzqs/1/)**.

One solution was to insert a `&nbsp;` in the `<p>`, as showed in this other **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0mdcLzqs/2/)**, but this is not a very clean solution: it pollutes the text that is written inside.

I can take advantage of JavaScript and jQuery, but a pure HTML and CSS solution is preferred

Any thought?

**UPDATE**
I forgot to say that the text should go also under the image so it cannot be floated or hidden

Comment: Tiny point: technically, `contenteditable` isn't a Boolean attribute so `<div class="text" contenteditable>` isn't strictly valid. However, it does work in all browsers, as far as I'm aware. The correct form is `<div class="text" contenteditable="true">`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply try margin-left:500px;

```
.text {
    min-height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin-left:500px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add overflow:hidden into an element that should not overlay a floating element:

http://jsfiddle.net/nothrem/0mdcLzqs/3/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="https://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1417021423914-070979c8eb34?fit=crop&fm=jpg&q=75&w=1050" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="text" contenteditable style="overflow:hidden">
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

UPDATE: you can use Javascript to change the overflow based on element's content

```
document.getElementsByClassName('text')[0].onblur = function() {
    if (this.innerHTML.replace(/<[^>]+>/, '')) { //remove HTML tags
        this.style.overflow = 'visible';
    } else {
        this.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    }
}
```

Blur fires after you finish editing, you may want to add another events, e.g. onkeyup, onmouseclick, etc.

Comment: I forgot to say that the text should go also under the image so it cannot be floated or hidden

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove div's and apply to image these css-styles:

```
display:    -moz-inline-stack;
display:    inline-block;
_overflow:  hidden;
*zoom:      1;
*display:   inline;
```

with

```
vertical-align: bottom;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not a big fan of floats unless necessary, I'd remove the `float: left` from the image CSS and add to the `.image, .text` one these two lines:

```
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
```

Answer (score 0):

**To get text under your image**

Set the container width to the width of your image, and set the position of your text with float left or right like this:

```
.container {
  width: 500px; // width of image
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
 .image, .text {
 position: relative;
}
.image {
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
overflow: hidden;
float: left;
}
.text {
min-height: 30px;
width:100%;
border-top: 1px solid #000;
float:left;
text-align:center;  
}
.clear{
clear: both;
}
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/65yvg0v0/)